# Fetch not responding

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have this App component which I want to get some data from my API on the back:

```
const App = () => {
  const [restaurants, setRestaurants] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          "http://localhost:3001/api/v1/restaurants"
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
        setRestaurants(data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("Cant fetch");
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    // <RestaurantContextProvider>
    <div className="container">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home restaurants={restaurants} />} />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/restaurants/:id/update"
            element={<UpdatePage />}
          />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/restaurants/:id"
            element={<RestaurantDetailPage />}
          />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
    // </RestaurantContextProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

If I change the element for a component in the Route element, it fetches but does not render.
What is wrong? I did not find the answer on the V6 documentation of the Router.

Edited:

If i add the fetch inside this component, it fetch the data OK.

```
const RestaurantsList = (restaurants) => {
  

  return (
    <div className="list-group">
      <table className="table table-hover table-dark">
        
        <tbody>
          {restaurants &&
            restaurants.map((res) => (
              <tr key={res.id}>
                <td>{res.name}</td>
                <td>{res.location}</td>
                <td>{"$".repeat(res.price_range)}</td>
                <td>Reviews</td>
                <td>
                  <button className="btn btn-warning">Update</button>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <button className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RestaurantsList;
```

Here it is the index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: I mean... maybe there's an error o the fetch as you are not updating the satate if theres an error?

Comment: I dont understand. If i fetch the data in a children, it works OK

Comment: did you try the render props of route ? `<Route render={(routerProps => <Home restaurants={restaurants} {...routerProps}  />`

Comment: You need to pass restaurants as dependency in useEffect hook. Based on dependency, rerender happens. Also use empty array instead of empty string in useState.

Comment: @Salman that didnt work.

Comment: @HichamELBSI that did not work. It throws fail to compile

Comment: @miouri your fetchData should return a promise. The way you wrote the method it's not following best practice. You can declare fetchData outside of useEffect and pass the method name as dependency in useEffect. Also you can use useCallback to wrap up fetchData for memoised version. For now you give a try like this

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData().then((data) => setRestaurants(data));
}, []);

Comment: @Salman I´ve tried this:

 const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/v1/restaurants");
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
      //setRestaurants(data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Cant fetch");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData().then((data) => setRestaurants(data));
  }, []);

But did not worked

Comment: What is the issue, what isn't working? We need more context/details.

Comment: I cant fetch the data with the code I mentioned

Comment: `fetchData` isn't called when `App` mounts?

Comment: @DrewReese idk where to call it, I think it is OK like that(?)

Comment: It's called in the `useEffect` hook callback when `App` component mounts. I don't see an issue here. The `useEffect` hook and `fetchData` call have nothing to do with routing/navigation. It's still unclear what the issue is. What are you expecting to happen? What are you doing that isn't working as you like? Can you walk us through that part so we understand what you are doing and what/where any issues  are?

Comment: @DrewReese Im trying to render the components I´ve recently added. See edited post.

Comment: @DrewReese the idea is to fetch the data in the App component, the pass through props to the RestaurantList component and render. If I put the fetch code inside the RestaurantList component, it fetchs the data OK.

Comment: You should destructure the passed `restaurants` prop from the props object, which you also named `restaurants` for some reason. I.E. it should probably be `const RestaurantsList = ({ restaurants }) => { ...`.

Comment: @DrewReese sorry for being such an idiot, but I dont get it. About destructuring the props.

Answer (score 1):

You have likely successfully called `fetchData` in the mounting `useEffect` hook in `App`, and are passing the `restaurants` state to `Home` on a `restaurants` prop:

```
<Route path="/" element={<Home restaurants={restaurants} />} />
```

But in the routed component you are not accessing the `restaurants` prop at all, but instead have named the props object `restaurants` and are trying to map it. React props objects, if assigned to an argument, are ***always*** defined, but is an object, not an array.

```
const RestaurantsList = (restaurants) => { // <-- props object is restaurants
  return (
    <div className="list-group">
      <table className="table table-hover table-dark">
        <tbody>
          {restaurants &&
            restaurants.map((res) => (
              <tr key={res.id}>
                <td>{res.name}</td>
                <td>{res.location}</td>
                <td>{"$".repeat(res.price_range)}</td>
                <td>Reviews</td>
                <td>
                  <button className="btn btn-warning">Update</button>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <button className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};
```

To resolve:

1. Access `restaurants.restaurants` to get to the *actual* `restaurants` prop that is an array to be mapped.

   ```
   const RestaurantsList = (restaurants) => {
     return (
       <div className="list-group">
         <table className="table table-hover table-dark">
           <tbody>
             {restaurants.restaurants.map((res) => (
               <tr key={res.id}>
                 ...
               </tr>
             ))}
           </tbody>
         </table>
       </div>
     );
   };
   ```

   By convention though, you should name the props object `props` so it's more clear what it is and doesn't lead to the confusion you have.

   ```
   const RestaurantsList = (props) => {
     return (
       <div className="list-group">
         <table className="table table-hover table-dark">
           <tbody>
             {props.restaurants.map((res) => (
               <tr key={res.id}>
                 ...
               </tr>
             ))}
           </tbody>
         </table>
       </div>
     );
   };
   ```
2. Use props [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get to the `restaurants` prop.

   ```
   const RestaurantsList = (props) => {
     const { restaurants } = props;
     return (
       <div className="list-group">
         <table className="table table-hover table-dark">
           <tbody>
             {restaurants.map((res) => (
               <tr key={res.id}>
                 ...
               </tr>
             ))}
           </tbody>
         </table>
       </div>
     );
   };
   ```

   or

   ```
   const RestaurantsList = ({ restaurants }) => {
     return (
       <div className="list-group">
         <table className="table table-hover table-dark">
           <tbody>
             {restaurants.map((res) => (
               <tr key={res.id}>
                 ...
               </tr>
             ))}
           </tbody>
         </table>
       </div>
     );
   };
   ```

In `App` component, please ensure you maintain an array state invariant so the `restaurants` prop in children is always a valid array and mappable by using an empty array `[]` as the initial state over an empty string `''`.

```
const [restaurants, setRestaurants] = useState([]);
```

Comment: for some reason is not working with your solution.... if I try to console.log to "debug" the state restaurants on the app, it does not get nothing.

Comment: @miouri What are where in `App` are you logging to debug? Is the request made, do you see it in your network tab in the browser's devtools? If so, what is the value of `console.log(data);` logged in the `useEffect`'s `fetchData` function?

Comment: i´m console.log inside the fetch function and after setting the state:

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          "http://localhost:3001/api/v1/restaurants"
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        setRestaurants(data);
        console.log(restaurants);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("Cant fetch");
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [restaurants]);

Comment: Maybe is something with Router? I´m using V6. I updated the code with the index.js, pls look at it.

Comment: @miouri React state updates are asynchronously processed, you can't log the `restaurants` state *right* after enqueueing an update as it will log the state value from the current render cycle, not what it will be in a subsequent render cycle after updating. Use `useEffect(() => console.log(restaurants), [restaurants]);` to log state updates.

Comment: @miouri Has this helped resolve your question/issue?